# Calculate number of probabilities

Tags: graphing-functions, matrices

I want to calculate a number of probabilities of `a+b+c=1`

For `a vary from 0 to 1 with an incrementing of 0.1`

For `b vary from 0 to 1 with an incrementing of 0.1`

For `c vary from 0 to 1 with an incrementing of 0.1`

The question is: how many cases or probabilities can i have from these conditions?
Thank u very much!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is, perhaps, directed to math.stackexchange.com. Just for fun and assuming an interpretation of the question: if the aim is to find the number of ways of selecting a triple (with replacement) from {0,0.1,0.2,...,1} that sums to 1. This is equivalent to integer partitioning 10  (just divide by 10).

Some approaches to counting:

```
tup = Tuples[Range[0, 10], 3];
res = Pick[tup, Plus @@@ tup, 10];
Length[res]
```

yields 66

or

```
ip = PadRight[IntegerPartitions[10, 3]];
c = Total@(Multinomial @@@ (Tally[#][[All, 2]] & /@ ip))
```

yields 66

You can display:`res/10.`:

```
{{0., 0., 1.}, {0., 0.1, 0.9}, {0., 0.2, 0.8}, {0., 0.3, 0.7}, {0., 
  0.4, 0.6}, {0., 0.5, 0.5}, {0., 0.6, 0.4}, {0., 0.7, 0.3}, {0., 0.8,
   0.2}, {0., 0.9, 0.1}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0.1, 0., 0.9}, {0.1, 0.1, 
  0.8}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6}, {0.1, 0.4, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5, 
  0.4}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.2}, {0.1, 0.8, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.9, 
  0.}, {0.2, 0., 0.8}, {0.2, 0.1, 0.7}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.6}, {0.2, 0.3, 
  0.5}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.4}, {0.2, 0.5, 0.3}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.7, 
  0.1}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.}, {0.3, 0., 0.7}, {0.3, 0.1, 0.6}, {0.3, 0.2, 
  0.5}, {0.3, 0.3, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.5, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.6, 
  0.1}, {0.3, 0.7, 0.}, {0.4, 0., 0.6}, {0.4, 0.1, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.2, 
  0.4}, {0.4, 0.3, 0.3}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.5, 0.1}, {0.4, 0.6, 
  0.}, {0.5, 0., 0.5}, {0.5, 0.1, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.5, 0.3, 
  0.2}, {0.5, 0.4, 0.1}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.}, {0.6, 0., 0.4}, {0.6, 0.1, 
  0.3}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.6, 0.3, 0.1}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.}, {0.7, 0., 
  0.3}, {0.7, 0.1, 0.2}, {0.7, 0.2, 0.1}, {0.7, 0.3, 0.}, {0.8, 0., 
  0.2}, {0.8, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.}, {0.9, 0., 0.1}, {0.9, 0.1, 
  0.}, {1., 0., 0.}}
```

Hence, 'probability a triple at random will sum to 10` is 66/11^3 $\approx 0.0495868$.